# Dynamically creating a floating context menu with listener for each item?

Tags: java, android

I've seen a few questions asking this for VB and C#, but nothing for Java/Android.  Basically I have an ArrayList of values, all numbers, and I want to provide the user an option for removing a specific entry.  What I want to do is when the user clicks a "Remove Entry" button, a floating context menu appears populated with options of the ArrayList entries, in order of which they appear in the list.  When they click a number in the menu, it is removed from the ArrayList.

I'm fairly new to menu creation, but I've created them via xml many times.  This is the first time I'm attempting to create a floating menu dynamically with an undetermined number of items.

Answer (score 1):

If the list of numbers is reasonably short from the UX point of view (i.e. users don't want to search/filter the list), you can use a [traditional single-choice list AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingAList). You just need to modify the example from the docs slightly:

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);

final CharSequence[] numbers = new CharSequence[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    numbers[i] = list.get(i).toString();
}

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setTitle("Remove entry:");
builder.setItems(numbers, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        list.remove(which);
    }
});
builder.create().show();
```

As you can see in the docs, the [`setItems`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28java.lang.CharSequence%5b%5d,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) method is overloaded to accept a `CharSequence` array. So basically, you need to convert the numbers to CharSequences before creating the `Dialog`. (`String` implements `CharSequence`, thus `toString()` does the job.)

In the `OnClickListener`, the index of the selected menu item is passed as `which` to the `onClick` method. As the menu item index and the list item index are the same, you can use `which` to remove the item from the actual list.

The same approach works for lists of floats, just format them according to locale.